# How to run LuaLaTeX only for tikzexternalize while running PDFLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, tikz-external, capacity

When I run PDFLaTex when using `\tikzexternalize`, for large files I get an error that the TeX capacity is exceeded (enlarging does not help). However, when I compile with LuaLaTeX it works (for small tikz files, compiling with PDFLaTeX works fine). If I use `\tikzexternaldisable` for the large tikz files, then PDFLaTeX also works fine, but then no PDF of the figure is created. Now I want to compile with PDFLaTeX, and only compile the external tikz figures with LuaLaTeX, how can I realize this?

In my preamble is use:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=Images/Tikz/] 
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]

\newcommand\includetikz[1]{
  \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}
  \filemodCmp{Images/#1.tex}{Images/Tikz//#1.log}%
  {\tikzset{external/force remake=true}\input{Images/#1}}
  {\input{Images/#1}}}
```

Then it is working when compiling with LuaLaTex. I added the following to my preamble to run my file with PDFLaTeX:

```
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex -enable-write18 -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
```

I also added `--enable-write18 --shell-escape` in the command line.  Then I tried to run it with PDFLaTeX, but I still get the memory error. How to resolve this?

In my document I use the following to insert the figure (created with Matlab2tikz):

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \setlength\fheight{0.8\textwidth}
  \setlength\fwidth{1\textwidth}
  \includetikz{BodeMag}
  \caption{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The first step is to make a *complete*  example that other can tests. Snippets are evil ...

Comment: I find that creating a graph in a separate file using the standalone document class is more convenient than externalizing graphics.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The problem is that when I use a simple example, compiling with PDFLaTeX works fine. Only for large tikz files I have this problem.

Comment: I didn't write "make a *simple* example" but "make a *complete* example". Such issues must be tested. So completeness is necessary, simplicity is a bonus. You could try to compile once with lualatex to get the pictures and then remove the `external/force remake=true` and fall back to pdflatex.